# Table body overflow is not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jquery in my project.

my requirement is set min-height for table body and I need scroll for overflow.

It is not working in chrome browser working fine in firefox

table body height overflow is not working in chrome

.....
.....

Comment: You should post the actual HTML and the stylesheet, or jQuery/Javascript code that attempts to set the style.

Answer (score 0):

Try set for tbody "display: block"